# ASP.NET MVC in IIS, RedirectToAction() and Redirect()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, iis-8

I am working with ASP.NET MVC 4 using Visual Studio 2015 community edition, and IIS 8.. I am beginner in this technology..

I created login page,
In my Login controller (action Index), I put `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")` to redirect the page when users enter correct username and password.. it works when I debug/run it in visual studio environment.. but when I publish it (let say the name is MyPublishedWeb), create application in IIS, and browse it, the URL will look like this: `localhost/MyPublishedWeb/Login/Index`

The problem is when I login succesfully, it redirects me to `localhost/Home/Index`, instead of `localhost/MyPublishedWeb/Home/Index`, and it gives error..

But when I change `RedirectToAction()` to `Redirect()`, it works both in visual studio environment and IIS..

What do I miss?
Why `RedirectToAction()` doesn't work in IIS application?

Comment: RedirectToAction constructs url based on Controller and Action name specified as parameters to the method, whereas in case of Redirect(), you specify the url where you want to redirect the user. This is probably why Redirect() is working in your case but RedirectToAction() doesn't.

Comment: Thanks Harsh, but when do we need to use RedirectToAction() if it doesn't work in IIS application? It makes me confuse, should we only use Redirect() in all of our action methods instead of RedirecToAction()..

Comment: Are you using `RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`or `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")` (the 2nd is correct)

Comment: I use return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); and then I changed it into return Redirect("~/Home/Index"); because RedirectToAction() doesn't work in my IIS application..

Answer (score 0):

Try These 2 Steps:

1. Use  `[HttpPost]` in your controller
2. Upon successful login return `RedirectToAction("Index","Home")`;

`Controller.RedirectToAction` Method

Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser to make a GET request to the specified action. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: Yes, I tried those two steps.. I use attribute [HttpPost] in my Login controller. and I also use return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home") upon successful login. But it only works in visual studio environment, not in IIS application..